# Finding out the least value of $m$ and $n$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m<n$ and the last three digits of $(2978)^m$ and $(2978)^n$ are same then the question is to find out the least value of $m$ and $n$

---

I noticed that $$(2978)^n-(2978)^m=1000k$$for some positive $k$.I could not proceed after this.Any ideas?Thanks.

Comment: Difference is divisible by 1000 if and only if it is divisible by $2^3$ and also divisible by $5^3$.  For first, $2978^0 \equiv 1$, $2978^1 \equiv 2$, $2978^2 \equiv 4$, $2978^n \equiv 0 \pmod{8}$ for $n \ge 3$, so $2978^n \equiv 2978^m \pmod{8}$ requires $m \ge 3$.  For mod 125, 2978 is relatively prime to 125 so its powers form a cycle.  Furthermore, the order of the cycle divides $\varphi(125) = 100$.  So then, you just need to try powers of $2978 \equiv -22\pmod{125}$ mod 125 which divide 100, e.g. $(-22)^2$, $(-22)^4$, $(-22)^5$, etc. until you get 1.

Comment: It looks like $(-22)^{20} \equiv 26 \pmod{125}$ and $(-22)^{50} \equiv -1 \pmod{125}$.  Any proper divisor of 100 has to divide either 20 or 50, so that means the order of the cycle is 100.  That would make the smallest answer $m=3$, $n=103$.