# If $m,n\in \Bbb N$ s.t $m<n$ and the last three digits of $(2978)^m$ and $(2978)^n$ are same, what are the least value of $m$ and $n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, binomial-theorem

[This question is duplicate of this.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2222855/finding-out-the-least-value-of-m-and-n)But it was solved by number theory and we have not been taught.I wonder if this can be solved by using Binomial theorem?

> If $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m<n$ and the last three digits of $(2978)^m$ and $(2978)^n$ are same then the question is to find out the least value of $m$ and $n$

---

I understand $$(2978)^n-(2978)^m=1000k$$for some positive $k$.
I also understood that m,n should be greater than equal to 3. By binomial theorem i found that last three digits of $(2978)^n,(2978)^m$ are equivalent to that $(978)^m and(978)^n$. How to do further?

Comment: Maybe you should learn number theory by yourself then, it's not too hard)